# Generate new OAuthAccessToken and OAuthAccessTokenSecret in code

Tags: java, token, access-token, twitter4j

Can I generate new OAuthAccessToken and OAuthAccessTokenSecret in code? May be using twitter4j? I have:

```
configurationBuilder.setDaemonEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("MyCoonsumerKey")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("MyConsumerSecret")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("MyAccessToken")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("MyAccessTokenSecret");
```

But I want generate new Tokens in process in code. Can I do it? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to that is:

***No***, you can't generate OAuthAccessToken or OAuthAccessTokenSecret by yourself via Twitter4J.

Taken from https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview, we learn:

> In order to make authorized calls to Twitter’s APIs, an application must first obtain an OAuth access token on behalf of a Twitter user (or, issue Application-only authenticated requests, when user context is not required).

Moreover, ...

> ... an access token will be invalidated if a user explicitly revokes an application in the their Twitter account settings, or if Twitter suspends an application.

Conclusion:

You have to generate access token & secret in "*their Twitter account settings*". For reference, please find the full guide under: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction

Note well, a mobile phone number is required.